# Apache Spark with custom InputFormat for HadoopRDD

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am currently working on Apache Spark. I have implemented a Custom `InputFormat` for Apache Hadoop that reads key-value records through TCP Sockets. I wanted to port this code to Apache Spark and use it with the `hadoopRDD()` function. My Apache Spark code is as follows:

```
public final class SparkParallelDataLoad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iterations = 100;
        String dbNodesLocations = "";
        if(args.length < 3) {
            System.err.printf("Usage ParallelLoad <coordinator-IP> <coordinator-port> <numberOfSplits>\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf();
        jobConf.set(CustomConf.confCoordinatorIP, args[0]);
        jobConf.set(CustomConf.confCoordinatorPort, args[1]);
        jobConf.set(CustomConf.confDBNodesLocations, dbNodesLocations);

        int numOfSplits = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        CustomInputFormat.setCoordinatorIp(args[0]);
        CustomInputFormat.setCoordinatorPort(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkParallelDataLoad");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> records = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf, 
                CustomInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, 
                numOfSplits);

        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> points = records.map(new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>, LabeledPoint>() {

            private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Function.class);
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1771348263117622186L;

            private final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
            @Override
            public LabeledPoint call(Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> tuple)
                    throws Exception {
                if(tuple == null || tuple._1() == null || tuple._2() == null)
                    return null;
                double y = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString(tuple._1.get()));
                String[] tok = SPACE.split(tuple._2.toString());
                double[] x = new double[tok.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; ++i) {
                    if(tok[i].isEmpty() == false)
                        x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i]);
                }
                return new LabeledPoint(y, Vectors.dense(x));
            }

        });

        System.out.println("Number of records: " + points.count());
        LinearRegressionModel model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(points.rdd(), iterations);
        System.out.println("Model weights: " + model.weights());

        sc.stop();
    }
}
```

In my project I also have to decide which Spark Worker is going to connect to which Data Source (something like a "matchmake" process with a 1:1 relation). Therefore, I create a number of `InputSplit`s equal to the number of data sources so that my data are sent in parallel to the `SparkContext`. My questions are the following:

1. Does the result of method `InpuSplit.getLength()` affect how many records a `RecordReader` returns? In detail, I have seen in my test runs that a Job ends after returning only one record, only because I have a value of 0 returned from the `CustomInputSplit.getLength()` function.
2. In the Apache Spark context, is the number of workers equal to the number of the `InputSplits` produced from my `InputFormat` at least for the execution of the `records.map()` function call?

The answer to question 2 above is really important for my project.

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: I think you are using `InputSplit.getLength` in a number of places in the question where you meant `InputFormat.getSplits`. Apologies if the confusion is with me.

Comment: I had to something similar, my sample project is on github, you check it here. https://github.com/animeshj/bigdata/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** Spark's `sc.hadoopRDD` will create an RDD with as many partitions as reported by `InputFormat.getSplits`.

The last argument to `hadoopRDD` called `minPartitions` (`numOfSplits` in your code) will be used as the hint to `InputFormat.getSplits`. But the number returned by `getSplits` will be respected no matter if it is greater or smaller.

See the code at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala#L168

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you also know whether the reading of data from `InputSplits` happen in parallel? To express the previous question differently: Is the RDD going to be created in parallel by retrieving data from the Data Sources?

Comment: A task will be created for each split. One task is picked up per worker CPU core. If you have enough worker cores, all splits will be done in parallel. Otherwise each core will do one split and then pick up more work when that is finished, until all tasks are done.